# asp.net profile table and german characters

Tags: c#, asp.net, oracle, encoding, special-characters

I have a question about storing special characters (umlauts, german characters, etc) in the profile tables in SQL with asp.net.

We feed this information into another database with form submissions, and we found that when these fields reached the end database, some characters like ö or ä, etc were coming in as their ascii codes like `&#228;` and `&#246;`.

I looked back into the aspnet_Profile table and looked for the source data and found that the characters had been stored that way in the database.

My question is. Is there a way to store these characters as ö or ä in sql server, or do I need to encode/decode (which?) when I pull them out of the profile to show on the webpage and insert into the end database (which is Oracle and can handle these characters).

if i have to encode/decode each field from the profile table, do i do it when i submit the data to the profile? or when i retrieve the data form the profile for the website/record insert to Oracle?

sorry if it's a newbie question, but i am a newbie!

Comment: Check the encoding of the database. Can you save those characters directly in a SQL editor?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is if you are directly building the SQL rather than using a parameter to pass in the value.

If you build an INSERT statement like:

```
string cmd = string.Format("INSERT INTO FOO (col) VALUES ({0})", value);
```

Oracle may not realize you are passing in a Unicode string and escape it. This also leaves you open to potential SQL injection hacks but that is a different matter.

You need to use a parameter for any values passed into the database. For example:

```
using (var conn = new OracleConnection(connectionString)) {
    using (var command = new OracleCommand("INSERT INTO FOO (col) VALUES (?)")) {
        command.Connection = conn;
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("?", value);
        command.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}
```